# How to group mysql first column and again by second id not losing unique combinations

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql, is it possible to iterate through results to further results.

I think what I'm trying to do is group by other id grouped by transid, but apparently that isn't what this type of sorting is called.

**Sample Data**

```
 id      transid  other id
------------------------------
|1      |1        |1        |
|2      |1        |1        |
|3      |1        |1        |
|4      |1        |2        |
|5      |1        |2        |
|6      |1        |2        |
|7      |2        |1        |
|8      |2        |1        |
|9      |2        |1        |
|10     |2        |2        |
|11     |3        |1        |
|12     |3        |1        |
```

**Expected Output**

```
 RESULT:
 id      transid  other id
------------------------------
|1      |1        |1        |
|4      |1        |2        |
|7      |2        |1        |
|10     |2        |2        |
|11     |3        |1        |
```

Comment: For each unique pair of `transid`, `otherid`, you want just the first `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,transid,other_id from table group by transid,other_id;
```

If your first column meant transid col ...
Grouping all those rows with same values of transid,other_id

Comment: You can't `select *` when grouping by particular columns.

Comment: Still invalid `sql`: which `id` should it pick?

Comment: @IsaacKleinman .. I am not sure why it won't work...? AFAIK the col on which we group should be selected... Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This is enough that I got what I needed, and it was first. Thanks so much. I just didn't have the right group by syntax and when I was looking it up all the examples seemed to be for other issues than the very simple thing I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use `GROUP BY` on multiple columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id), transid, other_id GROUP BY transid, other_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the min id for each pair of trans_id + other_id you need to use the min aggregate function and group by trans_id and other_id

```
SELECT MIN(id)
,      trans_id
,      other_id
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY trans_id
,        other_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT id, transid, "other id"
FROM
(SELECT id, transid, "other id",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transid, "other id") rn
FROM table)x
WHERE rn = 1
```

This is how you would do it using an RDBMS that provides analytical/windowing functions. I don't think `mysql` offers that.